# Is "I got lost trying to find" correct?

Tags: dependent-clause, when

I read this paragraph:

> - Why didn't you come to Alex's house last night? We were all expecting to see you there.
>   + Oh, I'm sorry about that. I got lost trying to find Alex's house.

Which one is correct?

1. I got lost trying to find ...
2. I got lost when I was trying to find ...

Am I right in thinking the correct one is "I got lost when I was trying to find..."?

Comment: More context needed.

Comment: More context added. @HotLicks

Comment: Either form is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"trying to find..." is an abridged or reduced adverbial clause equivalent to "when/as/while (subject) was trying to find..."

Therefore, you can say:

1. I got lost trying to find Alex's house.
2. I got lost when I was trying to find Alex´s house.
3. I got lost as I was trying to find Alex´s house.
4. I got lost while I was trying to find Alex´s house.

All of them have exactly the same meaning.